# WTL Child window event handling

Tags: c++, winapi, wtl

I am developing window application in that I am having 2 child windows on left and right side.
I want to handle input events for both windows separately. 
How to achieve it?

**My code:**

```
class EditorWindow : public DxWindow
{
public:
    CSplitterWindow m_vSplit;
    CPaneContainer m_lPane;
    CPaneContainer m_rPane; 
    PropertyDialog m_propertyWnd;
    DECLARE_WND_CLASS(_T("Specific_Class_Name"))

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(EditorWindow)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CREATE, OnCreate)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_DESTROY, OnDestroy)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, KeyHandler)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_KEYUP, KeyHandler)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, KeyHandler)
    END_MSG_MAP()

    LRESULT OnCreate(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL&)
    {
        CRect rcVert;
        GetClientRect(&rcVert);     
        m_vSplit.Create(m_hWnd, rcVert, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN);
        m_vSplit.SetSplitterPos(rcVert.Width()/1.4f); // from left
        m_lPane.Create(m_vSplit.m_hWnd);        
        m_vSplit.SetSplitterPane(0, m_lPane);   
        //m_lPane.SetTitle(L"Left Pane");

        m_rPane.Create(m_vSplit.m_hWnd);    
        m_vSplit.SetSplitterPane(1, m_rPane);       
        m_rPane.SetTitle(L"Properties");
        m_propertyWnd.Create(m_rPane.m_hWnd);
        //m_vSplit.SetSplitterPane(SPLIT_PANE_LEFT, md.m_hWnd);

        return 0;
    }
    LRESULT OnDestroy( UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL &bHandled )
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        bHandled = FALSE;
        return 0;
    }
    LRESULT KeyHandler( UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL &bHandled )
    {
        return 0;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WTL::CSplitterWindow and WTL::CPaneContainer do not forward the WM_KEYxxx and WM_MOUSExxx messages to their parent.

Derive your EditorWindow from WTL::CSplitterWindowImpl and your Panes from WTL::CPaneContainerImpl for instance:

```
class CMyPaneContainer : public CPaneContainerImpl<CMyPaneContainer>
{
public:
    DECLARE_WND_CLASS_EX(_T("MyPaneContainer"), 0, -1)
    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMyPaneContainer)
        MESSAGE_RANGE_HANDLER(WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, OnForward)
        MESSAGE_RANGE_HANDLER(WM_MOUSEFIRST, WM_MOUSELAST, OnForward)
        CHAIN_MSG_MAP(CPaneContainerImpl<CMyPaneContainer>)
    END_MSG_MAP()

    LRESULT OnForward(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
       if (uMsg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
           return bHandled = FALSE; // Don't forward WM_MOUSEWHEEL
       return GetParent().SendMessage(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
};


class EditorWindow : public CSplitterWindowImpl<EditorWindow, true, CWindow/*DxWindow*/> 
{
    typedef CSplitterWindowImpl<EditorWindow, true, CWindow/*DxWindow*/> baseClass;
public: 
    CMyPaneContainer m_lPane; 
    CMyPaneContainer m_rPane;  
    //PropertyDialog m_propertyWnd; 
    DECLARE_WND_CLASS(_T("Specific_Class_Name")) 

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(EditorWindow) 
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CREATE, OnCreate) 
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, KeyHandler) 
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_KEYUP, KeyHandler) 
        CHAIN_MSG_MAP(baseClass)
    END_MSG_MAP() 

    LRESULT OnCreate(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL&) 
    { 
        m_lPane.Create(m_hWnd);         
        m_lPane.SetTitle(L"Left Pane"); 

        m_rPane.Create(m_hWnd);     
        m_rPane.SetTitle(L"Properties"); 
        //m_propertyWnd.Create(m_rPane.m_hWnd); 
        SetSplitterPosPct(70); // 70% from left 
        SetSplitterPanes(m_lPane, m_rPane); 

        return 0; 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ALT_MSG_MAP()` in combination with `CContainedWindow` - you specify a message map ID for `ATL_MSG_MAP()` which you pass to `CContainedWindow`s constructor.

The ATL documentation for [`CContainedWindowT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e286yks%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) has an example.